# Proving this quotient is always even.

Tags: number-theory, summation, perfect-numbers

Let $n$ be an odd, composite integer.

Let $D$ equals the sum of the proper divisors of $n$ minus the last divisor, $d_j$. Also, let $n$ be a number such that $D \gt \frac{1}{2} \times{n}$. Let $d_i$ be the $i$th divisor of $n$. Also, let $j$ be the number of proper divisors and $j$ is odd.

So, $$D = 1 + d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_{j-1}$$

I want to prove that $$\frac{D}{d_1-1}$$ is always even.

Some facts I've figured out: $d_1$ is always prime; $d_i$ is always odd; $D$ is even since the sum of an even number of integers is even; and $d_1-1 \ge 2$ and is always even.

Edit: fixed wording

Comment: What if $n = p^2$ for p prime? As I understand your definition, that means D = 1? (Since there are only 2 proper divisors, 1 and p, and D omits the last one.) But then $D/(d_1 - 1)$ isn't an integer.

Comment: I mistakenly didn't specify that $j$ was the number of proper divisors. I fixed that. That condition excludes squares of primes since then $j = 2$.

Comment: What about cubes of primes? If $n = p^3$, then $D = 1 + p$, and $D/(d_1-1) = (1+p)/(p-1)$, which is not an integer in general.

Comment: For $p = 3$, it is an integer. However you are correct in general. I should've been more specific. I'll update the question.

Comment: Is there some broader context for this? Where is D coming from? Requiring D > n/2 rules out lots of small n values.

Comment: It has to do with perfect numbers and proving this will allow me to progress into a contradiction. $D$ is a value I'm using to push the proof. I do want to rule out all the values that can't possibly be perfect numbers. requiring $D\gt \frac{n}{2}$ is an actual requirement I found.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. $n = 125$ is odd and composite, $j=3$ is composite, the divisors are $1$, $5$, $25$, $D=6$ and $d_1 - 1$ = 4.  $\dfrac D {d_1-1}$ is not an integer, much less an even integer.

Comment: You're correct, I forgot to add a constraint on $D$. I'll update the wording. I meant to say that $D \gt \frac{1}{2} \times{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false, the first number where $\frac{D}{d_1-1}$ is odd is $2,205$.